# R data.table - categorical values in one column to binary values in multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have one data.table with 2 columns ID and X, where X contains categorical values (a, b, c)

```
ID X
1  a
2  c
3  b
4  c
```

I would like to transform X into 3 binary columns where the column names are a, b and c

```
ID a b c
1  1 0 0
2  0 0 1
3  0 1 0
4  0 0 1
```

What will be a good way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: See `?table` (`table(data)`) and, probably, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442207/contingency-table-with-r) might help

Answer (score 2):

Using `dcast` from `data.table`,

```
dcast(dt, ID ~ X, value.var = 'X', fun = length)
#   ID a b c
#1:  1 1 0 0
#2:  2 0 0 1
#3:  3 0 1 0
#4:  4 0 0 1
```

Comment: thanks! work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option from `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
     mutate(V1 = 1) %>% 
     spread(X, V1, fill= 0)
#  ID a b c
#1  1 1 0 0
#2  2 0 0 1
#3  3 0 1 0
#4  4 0 0 1
```